# React Native: Why not just use Navigation hooks all the time?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I've built one or two RN apps for work and whenever I struggle with passing a navigation component for one reason or another  `useNavigation` always saves my bacon.

So if you can use this to access the navigation component from anywhere in your app without having to prop drill it... why not always use it?

Is it solely because the app might employ nested navigation stacks or is there some other reason?

Comment: There is no reason to dont use `useNavigation` hook, is a hooks adventages, you can reused a function wherever you want (and when the scope allows you)

Answer (score 0):

The `navigation` prop is passed to all components that are defined as `screens` in a react-native navigator, e.g. a `Stack.Navigator`. Thus, in these screens we have access to it. Why should we not use it directly?

In my opinion we should only use `useNavigation` when there is no other choice. This is not because it breaks something, but because we should not introduce a dependency to a hook when it is not needed. However, this might be personal preference.

That said, the `useNavigation` hook is a method that was introduced in react-native-navigation v5.x in order to

> give access to the navigation object. It's useful when you cannot pass the navigation prop into the component directly, or don't want to pass it in case of a deeply nested child.

If we keep in mind that the `navigation` prop is only passed to `screen` components, we need to take care of navigation ourselves in nested components that are not `screens` listed in the navigator.  Suppose that `Screen` is a screen defined in a `Stack.Navigator`. The `navigation` prop is passed. Suppose that in `SomeComponentThatNeedsToNavigate` has a child that needs to navigate somewhere else. It can't. It has no access to the `navigation` prop.

There is of course an obvious way to solve this (which I am sure you are aware of).

```js
const Screen = ({navigation}) => {
    return <SomeComponentThatNeedsToNavigate navigation={navigation} />
}
```

However, this quickly gets out of hands when `there is a deeply nested child` that needs access to the `navigation` prop.

That is the reason `useNavigation` was introduced and is said so in the [react navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/5.x/connecting-navigation-prop) documentation.

> An ordinary component that is not a screen component will not receive the navigation prop automatically. For example in this GoToButton component:

> To resolve this exception, you could pass the navigation prop in to GoToButton when you render it from a screen, like so: `<GoToButton navigation={props.navigation} />.`

Or as an alternative

> Alternatively, you can use the useNavigation to provide the navigation prop automatically (through React context, if you're curious).

To summarize: **NO** there is no disadvantage or advantage in using `useNavigation`. Since I have never faced an issue with `useNavigation` myself during my work, I have checked their Github issue page and have not found any issue concerning `useNavigation` which makes me more confident that there is none in general. However, as I said earlier we generally should not introduce a dependency if it is not needed.